# Redirect to different area based on role in forms authentication on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am working on MVC with EF, Can Some one help with the below scenario.
I am using Forms Authentication in MVC 5.
I made a jquery ajax call to controller to login the user by sending username and pwd, Upon success I am setting the forms authentication cookie, and checking the role of the user. Here I am struck. I am using RedirectToAction method to navigate to different areas based on the role. But Its not navigating.
My Return statement is

```
if (roleProvider.IsUserInRole(userName, "Buyer"))
{
return RedirectToAction("Index", "BHome", new { area = "Buyer" });
}
```

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 2):

you can't redirect a user from an ajax call.  The ajax call is async so it will stay on the same page.  to redirect then you will need to add a window.location to the success of your ajax call

```
success: function(result){
    if(result.Success){
        window.location = '@Url.Action("newAction", "newController")';
    }
}
```